# Proof: Pivotal Quantity

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

Can anyone give me a clue of how to address this theorem?

> Suppose that $T$ es a real-valued statistic. Suppose that $Q(t,\theta)$ es a monotone function of $t$ for each value of $\theta\in \Theta$. Show that if the pdf of $T$, $f(t|\theta)$, cab be expressed in the form
>
> \begin{equation}
> f(t|\theta)=g(Q(t, \theta))\left|\frac{d}{dt}Q(t,\theta)\right|
> \end{equation}
>   for some function $g$, then $Q(t,\theta)$ is a pivot.

I know it is also useful to use the change of variable theorem, but i do not see how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer to this question is here: [Proof: Pivotal Quantity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197709/proof-pivotal-quantity), in the Cross Validated community